# Removing one-to-many related models using Django

Tags: python, django

I have the below models defined in Django and am looking for a way to delete all the cookies associated with a site.

**models.py**

```
class Site(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=settings.MAX_CHAR_COUNT)

class Cookie(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    value = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    host = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cookies')
```

I tried the following but got an error:

```
site_object.cookies.delete()

AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
site_object.cookies.all().delete()
```

In your example you are calling the manager instead of the delete method.